# How to prevent raspberry to connect with open wifi?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, wifi, wireless

Actually i am working on a project. I want my raspberry to stay connected with my DSL wifi. But raspberry connect with a open wifi automatically . Thats why i lose connection.

Please help me that how i can stay connected my raspberry pi 3 with my home wifi.

I am using Rasbian OS

Thanks

Comment: What operating system you are using? Can you please edit the question and copy your `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` to it? Does it connect to an open network without any entry for it?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file and add the open network like this:

```
network={
    ssid=""
    key_mgmt=NONE
    disabled=1
}
```

Setting the SSID (wifi name) between the quotes `""`.

I have no open wifi available to try this, but it should work. I found this info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80550/how-to-prevent-wpa-supplicant-from-connecting-to-a-network), credits to lgeorget if it is correct.

Comment: For me this is unclear. Does wpa_supplicant connect to an open network without an entry in `wpa_supplicant.conf` or with an empty `wpa_supplicant.conf`?

Comment: I am not sure it will connect if you don't specify it in `wpa_supplicant.conf` or with an empty file.
Though what OP is asking about should work with this. [key_mgmt=NONE](https://wiki.netbsd.org/tutorials/how_to_use_wpa_supplicant/) should be the way to say no password to it, and `disabled=1` make the system ignore it